# Create a custom "you dont have permission" message

Tags: permissions

How can I create a custom "you don't have permission" message? 
I'd like to display some html here. Is that possible?

Comment: For what? Where?

Comment: For example, on this screen: https://www.evernote.com/l/ALFpmNjLGj1K_6Ua1sMNwJC-TxLkL7hKtcM   I'd like to add some custom html here.